# Installing Windows and Uninstalling MacOS from a Mac Laptop?

Tags: windows, macos

I have a Mac Laptop with the MacOS running in it currently, I want to install Windows in this laptop and have it as the only Operating System, ie., also remove the MacOS.

What should I do? How should I proceed?

Comment: What versions of `OSX` and `Windows` are you looking to install exactly? In either case the current version of `Bootcamp` supported by your laptop would be required.  The simplest way would be to format the HDD and install `Windows` and of course install Bootcamp.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of Mac OS X alltogether, you could simply format your hard drive during the Windows installation process.

1. Insert the Windows CD
2. Boot from it
3. When you reach the section where you are asked if you want to format the drive, format it
4. Install Windows on the now free partition
5. Proceed to the end of the installation process

At this point, when you reboot your Mac, it will boot directly into Windows.

Comment: I am correct in saying, you do not have to remove the Mac OS initially, just follow your steps above & voila..its as simple as that

Comment: @Simon yes, because if you follow the steps above, Mac OS would be removed anyway

Comment: Excellent...One last query when do I insert the Windows CD, before powering up or whilst in Mac OS and rebooting ?

Comment: @Simon it is better if you do it whilst in Mac OS, because the Windows CD must be already inside your optical drive when the computer boots, in order to be allowed to choose it as a boot source

Comment: Ok fine....So insert & reboot, good to know thx alot